# fgetc() Creating Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linux, fgetc

I made the file "wor.txt" in the same program and i closed its write stream. But when i try to access it in first run(I created the file) it gives segmentation fault but when i re-run this program it runs successfully.

When i delete the automatically generated file and run the program again it gives Segmentation fault and on 2nd run(Without deleting the file) it runs successfully again.

NOTE: There is data in the textfile hence it is not empty(I have seen it after the first run in the file manager)

```
FILE *fp1= fopen("wor.txt","r");

FILE *f1= fopen("wordsa.txt","ab+");

if((f1==NULL)||(f2==NULL)){
printf("f1 or f2 is null");
}

char c='0';
while((c)!=EOF){
printf("Here is one marker\n");
    c=fgetc(fp1); //This Line gives error
printf("Here is another marker\n"); 
    fputc(c,f1);
}
```

Comment: `f1==NULL` -> `fp1==NULL`. If your code had been properly formatted you would havee seen this by yourself. Also you should use a consistent naming convention: call both variables `f1`and `f2` or `fp1` and `fp2`.

Comment: after detecting `fp1 == NULL` (at least I assume that in your code you check for `f2` instead) you continue anyway

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is no sufficient for `EOF`, change the type to `int`.

Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) of `fgetc()`, it returns an `int` and you should use the same datatype for storing the return value and further use.

That said, when either of `f1` or `fp1` is `NULL`, you are continuing anyways, accessing those file pointers, which may create UB. You should make some sense of that NULL check and either `return` or `exit` so that the code accessing tose pointers are not reached.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect check.

To properly detect opening of the stream, check `fp1`, not `f2`.  Then code will fail gracefully when the files do not open properly rather than seg fault.

```
FILE *fp1= fopen("wor.txt","r");
FILE *f1= fopen("wordsa.txt","ab+");

// if((f1==NULL)||(f2==NULL)){
if((f1==NULL) || (fp1==NULL)){

  printf("f1 or fp1 is null");
}
```

Also use `int c` as `fgetc()` typically returns 256 + 1 different values (`unsigned char` values and `EOF`) and a `char` is insufficient to uniquely distinguish them.